# Google Play ANR com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener.onBillingSetupFinished

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play, in-app-purchase

We are getting excessive ANR reports in Google Play and it is putting our game above the ANR "Bad behavior" threshold.

Below is what most of the logs look like:

```
#00  pc 00000000000e1aaf  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-UpZm6V6zLj2a-Tg-QXAtkg==/lib/arm/libunity.so (???)
  #00  pc 000000000000045d  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-UpZm6V6zLj2a-Tg-QXAtkg==/oat/arm/base.odex (Java_com_unity3d_player_ReflectionHelper_nativeProxyInvoke__JLjava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_Object_2+156)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke (Native method)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.a (unavailable)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1.invoke (unavailable)
  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke (Proxy.java:913)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.BillingClientStateListener.onBillingSetupFinished
  at com.android.billingclient.api.zzae.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:790)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7000)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:441)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

We have tried upgrading from Unity In App Purchasing 2.2.2 to 3.1.0 but the problem remains.

Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Another example:

```
 #00  pc 000000000006b4e8  /system/lib64/libc.so (nanosleep+8)
  #00  pc 000000000054c59c  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (???)
  #00  pc 00000000005591a4  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (???)
  #00  pc 000000000056b524  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (???)
  #00  pc 000000000052cf88  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/lib/arm64/libil2cpp.so (???)
  #00  pc 00000000002de020  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (???)
  #00  pc 000000000017e5b4  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (???)
  #00  pc 000000000017e4cc  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/lib/arm64/libunity.so (???)
  #00  pc 00000000000006c0  /data/app/com.doubletapsoftware.basketballbattle-joHdJRehI4I_7r70Dhl7FQ==/oat/arm64/base.odex (Java_com_unity3d_player_ReflectionHelper_nativeProxyInvoke__JLjava_lang_String_2_3Ljava_lang_Object_2+208)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.nativeProxyInvoke (Native method)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper.a (unavailable)
  at com.unity3d.player.ReflectionHelper$1.invoke (unavailable)
  at java.lang.reflect.Proxy.invoke (Proxy.java:913)
  at com.android.billingclient.api.SkuDetailsResponseListener.onSkuDetailsResponse
  at com.android.billingclient.api.zzac.run
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:795)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6861)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:450)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing a bit more of the log? Might also be worth posting to [Unity Forums under IAP](https://forum.unity.com/forums/unity-iap.112/). Jeff replies quite frequently and usually helps out.

Comment: That is the whole log. I have added another example to bottom of post. Thanks I have posted the question at the Unity Forums IAP section.

Answer (score 2):

You must desymbolicate the stack trace, especially functions for libil2cpp.so, otherwise, it's impossible to say what's wrong.

You might be using AndroidJavaProxy (or a plugin that uses it).
Did you notice any pattern? on internal debugging
Such a crash used to happen in the past if you closed the app, but that should be fixed. Though stuff like changing a scene might have something to do with it, depending on your setup.

Comment: We always upload the IL2CPP.symbols.zip file that is generated by Unity. But that is still how the ANR's will show in Google Play.

Answer (score 0):

We were having the sku response listener issues because we were using meta data to localize prices, after we removed localization the ANR went away.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hey Ray. How did you then show the correct price in each country if you removed use of the localization?